# Redirect based on query

Tags: perl

I have the following code:

```
my $uri=$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'};
if ($uri=~/\/\?render=xml){
 redirect(301,"Moved Permanently","urlsubstring");
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is if a user goes anywhere on my site if the page looks like `http://wwww.something.com/about/?render=xml` we perform a redirect to the url without the `render=xml portion`. As you can see what im concerned with is the `render=xml` query portion of the script.

So,

i need to update the logic to perform the redirect and then i will need a substring based on the position of the `?render=xml` against the `url`.

Here's my substring code:

```
$pos = index($uri,"?render=xml");
$newuri = substr($uri,0,$pos);
```

**I'm very new to perl so i just am looking for some assistanvce**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, you have not terminated your search pattern.

```
my $uri=$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'};
if ($uri=~/\/\?render=xml/){
 redirect(301,"Moved Permanently","urlsubstring");
}
```

but you can just do a straight search and replace.
try this.

```
    $uri = "http://www.something.com/about/?render=xml";
    $uri =~ s/\?render\=xml/newurlstring/g;
    print $uri
```

Untested, but you would more than likely have something like this as your code.

```
my $uri=$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'};
$uri =~ s/\?render\=xml/newurlstring/g;
```

which will return $uri as http://www.something.com/about/newurlstring

or if you just want to dump the ?render=xml portion and only use $uri as http://www.something.com/about/

```
my $uri=$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'};
$uri =~ s/\?render\=xml//g;
```

Comment: forgot to add this, if you want to escape the first / you must do `$uri =~ s/\/\?render\=xml//g;`